# How to set different column in table to be different width in css?

Tags: html, css

There is a table which contain 3 columns.
Now i want to set the first column 100px width,the second column 200px and the last column 300px.
It is a awkward to set all the td with a id which inicate which columns it is .
Is there a more wise way to do ?

Comment: Did you try using element:last-child {...} selector?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your table has standard markup, you can use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` to target specific cells in each row. You can substitute any number into `nth-child`, if your table has more columns.

```css
/* nth-child(1) = the first td in each tr */
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  }

/* the second */
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

/* the third */
td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 300px;
  background: #bbb;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in CSS using nth-child:

```css
#myTable tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#myTable tr td:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}
#myTable tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
}
#myTable tr td:last-child {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>100px</td>
  <td>200px</td>
  <td>300px</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If there's more than 3 columns you can just specify nth-child(x)..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`nth-child`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo) to do this:

```css
table tr td {
  padding:0;  
}
table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width:100px;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width:200px;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>100px</td>
    <td>200px</td>
    <td>300px</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **Hint:** The columns are wider than the defined width on CSS, because there is a default cellpadding. To remove the padding you can use the additional CSS rule (on this example the rule `table tr td`).